# Offset anchor for fixed header, but keep perma link intact

Tags: html, css, wordpress, anchor, offset

Added some code to my WordPress to make it add anchor links to all `h2` headlines. Furthermore, it is showing a small chain logo in front of each headline, when it is hovered.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Normal headline]

[image: Hovered headline]

This is my HTML markup:

```
<h2 id="contact">
  <a class="anchor" href="#contact">
    <i class="fa fa-link" title="Permalink"></i>
  </a>
  Contact us
</h2>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
h2 a.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding: 0.75em 8px 0.75em 4px;    
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  display: none;
}

h2:hover a.anchor {
  display: block;
}
```

However, my page does have a fixed navigation header, so the anchor link needs a little offset. Otherwise, my text content is hidden beneath the fixed header.

I added this code, to achieve the offset:

```
h2:before {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  height: 125px;
  margin-top: -125px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately, the chain logo moves up now and is shown 125px above its original position. How can I get both, the chain logo **in front** of the headline and the 125px **offset** to cope with the fixed header?

My implementation is losely based on [this article](http://www.bigemployee.com/adding-id-attributes-to-h2-tags-in-wordpress-to-use-as-anchor-tag), which unfortunately is down today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/p6nkvj3v/12/))

HTML

```
<div class="anchor-wrapper" id="contact">
    <h2>
        <a class="anchor" href="#contact">
            <i class="fa fa-link" title="Permalink"></i>
        </a>
        Contact us
    </h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a.anchor {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left: -1.2em;
    width: 1em;
}
h2:hover a.anchor {
    opacity: 1;
}
.anchor-wrapper:before {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    height: 125px;
    margin-top: -125px;
}
```